# In python, how to subtract two columns of excel file having time values and creating new column of it?

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, time, subtraction

I have an excel  database like this:

[ExcelTimeData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWMIg.png)

I want to  get new column (ResponseTime) = (EndTime-StartTime) using python. I am using following python code:

```
     import pandas as pd
     import numpy as np
     from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
     new = pd.read_excel("single_file.xlsx") 
     sf=pd.DataFrame(new)
     sf['Res_Time'] = sf['EndTime'] - sf['StartTime'])
```

it is showing me this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'
```

How to subtract time values in two columns ?

Comment: sf['EndTime'] is in datetime format?

Comment: yes. it is recorded as hh:mm:ss format

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to substract two strings, in order to work with dates first you must convert the columns to datetime using [`.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

```
sf['EndTime'] = pd.to_datetime(sf['EndTime'], format='%H:%M:%S')
sf['StartTime'] = pd.to_datetime(sf['StartTime'], format='%H:%M:%S')
```

With `format`, you can change the string parsing, check [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).